# How to create multiple VM's in Azure with different specifications

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am looking to create approx. 15 virtual machines with Terraform, of which all have their own Size in Azure such as B2S, B2MS etc. They also have different sized disks. I understand that you can use Copy Index to loop through arrays, however I'm not sure of the best way to do this with VM's that have lots of properties that are different.

Is there a way to create a map object for each VM specification and then just loop through it with a Virtual Machine creation in the TF file? At the moment the only way I can see of doing it is creating a separate virtual machine resource in the main file and referencing each individual map file..

Comment: If they really are very different then it probably makes sense to define them as separate resources because you'd expect different lifecycles for them and to edit even more things about them over time. Looping over a list (or map) to create resources works nicely when you have things that are basically the same (eg you have instances that you are spreading across availability zones).

Answer (score 2):

Create a map as you mention with the vm prefix as the key and size as the value:

```
variable "vms" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    vm1 = "Standard_DS1_v2"
    vm2 = "Standard_ES2_v2"
  }
}
```

Create your VMS:

```
# Network Interfaces for each one of the VMs
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {

  # looping to create a resource for each entry in the map
  for_each            = var.vms

  # Accessing keys in the map by each.key
  name                = "${each.key}-nic"

  ...

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {

  # Looping to create a VM per entry in the map
  for_each              = var.vms

  # Accessing names of map entries
  name                  = "vm-${each.key}-we"

  # Here we make sure we access the corrrect
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key]]
  vm_size               = each.value

  ...

  os_profile {
    # Accessing names of map entries again
    computer_name  = "vm-${each.key}-we"
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

---

For brevity I didn't write down the whole example of creating azure vms. 
There's many attributes you'll have to fill in as you need them.

Docs about how to create Azure VMS: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html
Docs about resources and "looping" them: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html 
Terraform has seriously the best docs out there IMO.